# Why do powershell and python give different result for same command?

Tags: python, powershell

Why do this script in Python

```
import subprocess, io
p = subprocess.Popen(["powershell.exe", "Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.MainWindowTitle } |    Format-List Id,Name,Path"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in io.TextIOWrapper(p.stdout, encoding="utf-8"):
    line = " ".join(line.split())
    print(line)
```

and writing the command in Powershell

```
Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.MainWindowTitle } | Format-List Id,Name,Path
```

have different results?
For example this is some of the result from Powershell:

```
Id   : 7692
Name : NVIDIA Share
Path : C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA GeForce Experience\NVIDIA Share.exe

Id   : 7232
Name : Origin
Path : C:\Program Files (x86)\Origin\Origin.exe
```

And this is the same from Python:

```
Id   : 7692
Name : NVIDIA Share
Path :

Id   : 7232
Name : Origin
Path : C:\Program Files (x86)\Origin\Origin.exe
```

Sometimes Path is missing from Python results when it is in Powershell. Why is that and is there some way to fix this?

Comment: Are both processes elevated?

Comment: Both processes are elevated.

Comment: It's my understanding that if you want to run several processes and pipe the results from one into the next, you have to use the `shell=True` argument to `Popen()`.  Since you didn't do this, I have no idea how your command even pretended to work.

Comment: Using the ```shell=True``` argument didn't make any difference.

Comment: Are both x64 processes?

Comment: I think that @Bill_Stewart is right. I noticed the comment after I finished writing my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought, like [@Viet Hoang](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58985706/2150063), that this is a simple elevation problem (as that is usually the issue 90% of the time). So, in blind Sysadmin confidence I decided to test it. Let's launch PowerShell as Administrator, and run:

```
PS C:\> (New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)
True
```

Ok. Good. We have a true elevated PowerShell session. Let's launch Python, and prove once and for all that @Lolman doesn't know what he's doing, and prove that Python doesn't know how to launch a proper elevated PowerShell session:

```
PS C:\> python
Python 3.8.0 (tags/v3.8.0:fa919fd, Oct 14 2019, 19:21:23) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess, io
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(["powershell.exe", "(New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> for line in io.TextIOWrapper(p.stdout, encoding="utf-8"):
...     line = " ".join(line.split())
...     print(line)
...
True
```

Excellent! It returns, as expected... umm... uh-oh... `True` ........ well... ummmm... nuts. There goes that idea. @Lolman actually *did* know how to try that.

Ok. Now this calls for some creative thinking. Let's compare some entries I get:

***PowerShell***

```
PS C:\> Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.MainWindowTitle } | Format-List Id,Name,Path

...

Id   : 2660
Name : powershell
Path : C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe

Id : 31200
Name : Code
Path : C:\Users\HAL9256\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe

Id : 22804
Name : devenv
Path : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe

...
```

***Python***

```
PS C:\> python
Python 3.8.0 (tags/v3.8.0:fa919fd, Oct 14 2019, 19:21:23) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess, io
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(["powershell.exe", "Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.MainWindowTitle } | Format-List Id,Name,Path"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> for line in io.TextIOWrapper(p.stdout, encoding="utf-8"):
...     line = " ".join(line.split())
...     print(line)
...

Id   : 2660
Name : powershell
Path : 

Id   : 31200
Name : Code
Path :

Id   : 22804
Name : devenv
Path : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe

...
```

So, let's look at the differences between the processes that were displaying path information and those that were not. I see a lot of `Program Files (x86)` but not `Program Files`... hmmm... this looks like it's a 32 vs 64 bit problem.

To prove this, I launched the 32 bit `Windows PowerShell (x86)` as Administrator, and ran the same command:

***Windows PowerShell (x86)***

```
PS C:\> (New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)
True

PS C:\> Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.MainWindowTitle } | Format-List Id,Name,Path

...

Id   : 2660
Name : powershell
Path : 

Id   : 31200
Name : Code
Path :

Id   : 22804
Name : devenv
Path : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe

...
```

Aha! it *does* look like a 32 bit vs. 64 bit issue. Ok. So, let's prove this. Let's download Python 64 bit and try it again:

```
PS C:\> C:\Users\HAL9256\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe
Python 3.8.0 (tags/v3.8.0:fa919fd, Oct 14 2019, 19:37:50) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess, io
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(["powershell.exe", "Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.MainWindowTitle } |    Format-List Id,Name,Path"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> for line in io.TextIOWrapper(p.stdout, encoding="utf-8"):
...     line = " ".join(line.split())
...     print(line)
...

Id   : 2660
Name : powershell
Path : C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe

Id : 31200
Name : Code
Path : C:\Users\HAL9256\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe

Id : 22804
Name : devenv
Path : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe

...
```

Yes! We get all the information now. The PowerShell console runs in 64 bit, and therefore can see the full path and process information. Python by default is 32 bit, and therefore can't see the full path and process information for 64 bit processes. It is only by explicitly running the 64 bit version of Python (from an elevated session), that we will be able to see all the path and process information.

Comment: Now that's a thoroughly convincing answer.   Makes my answer now look like a comment.   I guess there still some little use in leaving it around for contextual reference.   Good sleuthing - upvoted.

Comment: Thank you for this clear and informative answer. Honestly, I had little understanding about what I was doing there. The issue was running 32 bit Python. Installed 64 bit version and it runs correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Process Path not showing is a pretty clear indication of lack of elevated access.

The sub-process is losing its Administration access even though you're running Python as Administrator.

You can properly validate by running the following check outside and inside Python:

```
(New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)
```